# cannot get textarea values from post in php

Tags: php, post, textarea

**Editcontact.php**

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="savecontact.php" id="form" name="form">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Specific Address in Office</td>
<td><textarea name="txtspecificaddress" id="txtspecificaddress" rows="4"   cols="50" placeholder="Type specific address within the office. e.g. Room  Number, Section Name or Division Name etc."><?php echo $_SESSION['oldspecificaddress']; ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**on savecontact.php,** 
I am retrieving 'txtspecificaddress' value

```
if(isset($_POST['txtspecificaddress']))
{   
$specificaddress=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['txtspecificaddress']    ));
}
echo $specificaddress;
```

but it shows nothing. I have checked the value of $_SESSION['oldspecificaddress']. Can Somebody help? I am new to PHP.

Comment: Because you are using `mysqli_real_escape_string` wrongly... please check manual how it should look http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Read the manual on the escaping function.

Comment: without form update?

Comment: You have no submit button so how are you submitting the form?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: And make sure you started the session

Comment: Do you always work with complicated things that require reading the manual, one like setting the clock on a vcr or a 500ft crane? Well there you go. Read and understand completely first. I have done both myself and never had a problem ;-)

Comment: RiggsFolly: I am submitting the form using <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Update Contact"/> inside the <form> tag

Comment: Fred: I commited my mistake. But I have started the Session on the top of the php page. and tried using htmlentities instead of mysqli_real_escape_string. But unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: You have answers below, ask them. Comments are growing here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Morning! That reading thing throws people all the time!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Morning! Well, either way... this question isn't going anywhere so I for one gave up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with mysqli :

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database_name");
if(isset($_POST['txtspecificaddress']))
{   
    $specificaddress = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['txtspecificaddress']));
}
echo $specificaddress;
```

or try this

```
if(isset($_POST['txtspecificaddress']))
{   
    $specificaddress = trim($_POST['txtspecificaddress']);
}
echo $specificaddress;
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` expects exactly 2 parameters and you have passed only 1 parameter.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: No. He is not. Please check the question Carefully. He is using the Procedural style.

Comment: Ooops, my bad, you're right. I was looking at the other answer when I typed that. Not my DV, but you could gain UV's by showing the OP how to use the function in their code.